# Acronyms in Tanya

Tags: acronyms, tanya

At the end of known editions of sefer hatanya, there is a a Luach Rashe Tevot, table of Acronyms. But through the lecture of the book I didn't find the significance of "דש''ע".
It's in daf 104b (page 208) in the penultimate line, in the statement:

> והוא ירידת האור והשפע דש''ע נהורין שבזוה''ק

I guess that it's obviously not shulchan arurch, nor Shiv'yn because 70 is "ע" and so it have to be "דע' נהורין".

So can someone help me? Perhaps "שבעים עלמין"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not an acronym it is the number 370. See [Lessons in Tanya here](https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7948/jewish/Epistle-3.htm#footnoteRef18a7948).